# How to append key values to a simple array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

This is the approach I am trying to realize in JavaScript to append the "path" key to the strings in response.data.

```
var arraySujets = [];
    arraySujets[path] = [];

for (let i in response.data) {
    arraySujets[i][path] = response.data[i];
}
```

My response.data ist just a simple array of strings:

> array:2 [
>         0 => "/example/path1"
>         1 => "/example/path2"
>       ]

However the above code returns a

> ReferenceError: path is not defined

Comment: where is the definition of the `path`variable?

Comment: arraySujets=response.data; ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several solutions can be applied here.

assuming,

```
data = ["/example/path1", "/example/path2" ]
```

Standart for-loop

```
arraySujets = [];
for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
  arraySujets[i] = {path: response.data[i]}
}
```

Foreach with arrow functions.

```
response.data.forEach(e => arraySujets.push({path: e}))
/*
*response.data.forEach(function(e) {
*  arraySujets.push({path: e})
*})
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
var arraySujets = {}; // This must be an object, not an array
arraySujets["path"] = [];
```

That will access the `path` key in the object `arraySujets`

Comment: I am still getting a "Reference Error: undefined" if I try to reference it in my for-loop with "arraySujets[i]['path']" then

Answer (score 0):

You may want to keep the responses in some objects.
You can try something like this:

```
var arraySujets = response.data.map(function(resp) {
  return {
    path: resp
  }
})
```